# Webservice (WCF / ASMX) with LINQ-To-SQL operability to the iPhone

Tags: ios, linq, wcf, linq-to-sql, asmx

I have an ASMX-Web Service and tested whether I can access the iPhone over the web wervice  url (using json instead of soap) and everything worked. What bothers me is if there is any possibility to exchange objects than Collections or primitive data types? Is it possible to send LINQ-TO-SQL objects to the iPhone and parse it as an Object defining the right class?

Example:

> LINQ-To-SQL Entity: Customer (server side)

The one solution I saw was to create an extra Object-Class, like cloning the Linq-To-SQL Entity and defining Data Members etc. Is this way to go, because there are dozens of tutorials which advices you to manually build your jason string with JavaScriptSerializer which is the wrong way to go than let it serializing automatically. Are there any people who did it that way before and are ready to share their experiences?

I'm really thankful for answers / solutions.

Comment: Just a note - ASMX and WCF are **NOT** the same thing, even though both are web services.  ASMX is legacy technology; if this is a service recently developed you should consider developing it as a WCF service instead.

Comment: It was developed as an ASMX web service. My question is about exchanging objects LINQ-To-SQL entities to the iPhone. (Eventually to program a new web service if it's capable to do this).